# how do I make a batch file that executes this command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, exif, exiftool

I am trying to make a batch file that executes the following DOS command:

```
exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%%e" "C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\belvedere"
```

(FYI, exiftool.exe is a script that extracts EXIF data from your digital photos. In the command above I am telling it to look in my desktop\belvedere directory and rename all photos with the Date_Time.extension, e.g. 20120131_113015.jpg)

If I paste the above command into the DOS command prompt, it works fine. However, if I paste this command into a text file, name it something.bat and run this batch file, it does not work well (it renames one photo to be "mHS.JPG" then gives errors. I believe that the % characters are the problem. Does anyone know how I can make a useful .bat file that runs this command?

I am using Windows 7, if this makes a difference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would venture to say you're right about the `%`, that's one of those characters that [needs escaping](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php). Trying replacing the `%` with `%%` for every instance.

Other than that, a .bat is just a command stored for later use, so everything else should go fine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... this helps somewhat... the batch file now writes the command correctly up until the .%%e part

Comment: @Tom: Have you tried `.%%%%e`?

Comment: @Tom: Not a problem.